# Karate - image response comparision

Tags: karate

A service that returns an image (`Content-Type == 'image/png'`) that needs validation against an expected Image.

I went thru the [awesome documentation](https://intuit.github.io/karate/) but could not find any lead. Has Karate offers any support for this? or how can we achieve this?

**EDIT:**

```
        ....
        Then status 200
        * def expImage = read('classpath:data/charts/expectedResponse.png')
        And match header Content-Type == 'image/png'
        * def getBase64 = function(x) {return getBase64Image(x) } 
        * def expI = expImage, getBase64
        * print expI
        * print "################"
        * def actI = response, getBase64
        * print actI
        * ....
```

I have tried with some js way, but could not make it work yet, someone help to make it work?

Comment: search the docs for `responseBytes`. if you mean a "smart" comparison of two images for "similarity" sorry, karate does not support it. maybe you can contribute :) there are some things we created for karate-robot: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-robot#image-locators